# How can I reduce the width of a table?

Tags: tables, line-breaking

I'd like to put this table in a page:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
\hline
\textbf{No.} & \textbf{Author (year)}                                                & \textbf{Country} & \textbf{Journal}                                                                                                         & \textbf{Title}                                                                                                         & \textbf{Research method} & \textbf{E-grocery model} & \textbf{costs impact} & \textbf{Greenhouse gas emission} \\ \hline

1.           & Ring and Douglas (2001)                                                    & Finland          & \textit{International Journal of Retail \& Distribution Management}                                                      & Viewpoint: reaching the consumer through e-grocery VMI                                                                                           & Empirical                & Ancillary                & Core                  & Absent                           \\

2.           & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}K‰m‰r‰inen,\\ SmÂros et al. (2001)\end{tabular} & Finland          & \textit{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}International Journal of Retail \& Distribution\\ Management\end{tabular}}            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Cost-effectiveness\\ in the e-grocery business\end{tabular}                                                           & Conceptual Analitycal    & Absent                   & Core                  & Absent                           \\

3.           & K‰m‰r‰inen et al. (2001)                                                   & Finland          & \textit{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}International Journal of Physical Distribution\\ \& Logistic Management\end{tabular}} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}The\\ reception box impact on home delivery efficiency in the e-grocery business\end{tabular}                         & Conceptual Analitycal    & Core                     & Core                  & Absent                           \\

4.           & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Punakivi\\ and Tanskanen (2002)\end{tabular}    & Finland          & \textit{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}International\\ Journal of Retail \& Distribution Management\end{tabular}}            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Increasing\\ the cost efficiency of e-fulfilment using shared reception boxes\end{tabular}                            & Analytical               & Ancillary                & Core                  & Absent                           \\

5.           & Hanne Siikavirta et al. (2003)                                             & Finland          & \textit{Journal of industrial ecology}                                                                                   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Effects\\ of e-commerce on greenhouse gas emissions\end{tabular}                                                      & Empirical                & Absent                   & Absent                & Core                             \\

6.           & Heejin Lim et al. (2009)                                                   & USA              & \textit{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}International Journal of Retail \& Distribution\\ Management\end{tabular}}            & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Web\\ content analysis of e-grocery retailers: a longitudinal study\end{tabular}                                      & Empirical                & Ancillary                & Absent                & Absent                           \\

7.           & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Durand\\ and Gonzalez-Feliu (2012)\end{tabular} & France           & \textit{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}The Seventh International Conference on City\\ Logistics\end{tabular}}                & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Urban\\ logistics and e-grocery: Have proximity delivery services a positive impact on\\ shopping trips?\end{tabular} & Conceptual Analitycal    & Core                     & Absent                & Core                             \\

8.           & Van Loon et al. (2014)                                                     & Germany          & \textit{Journal of Cleaner Production}                                                                                   & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}A\\ comparative analysis of carbon emissions from online retailing of fast moving consumer\\ goods\end{tabular}       & Analytical               & Absent                   & Absent                & Core                             \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

the problem is that is too width and half of it go outside the paper, because Latex write all the text in a cell using just one line. I think the best solution for each cell is divide the text in more lines, how can i do it?

I've tried to use the command `\\` but it doesn't work properly...Thanks for the help!

Comment: Instead of `c`, you can use `p{<width>}` to set explicit sizes for the column.

Answer (score 4):

Your table is very long, consequently it is very difficult to put in text width of document. With some tweaks I obtain the following:

[image]

For it I reduce size of fonts to `\scriptsize`, than instead of `tabular` I use `\tabularx` and define it width with temporary width of text. Also I define new column type L, which left aligned multi line content of cell. With this type of column I can omit tabulars, which you use for multi line cells.

For heading I select `makecell` package, and for horizontal lines package `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength\textwidth{16cm}
    \usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,makecell}
    \newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries\sffamily}
\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \scriptsize
        \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\hsize}{@{}c>{\raggedright}p{24mm}l>{\itshape}LLLccc@{}}
    \toprule
\thead{No.} & \thead{Author (year)} 
    & \thead{Country} & \thead{Journal} 
        & \thead{Title} & \thead{Research\\ method} 
            & \thead{E-grocery\\ model} & \thead{Costs\\ impact} 
                & \thead{Greenhouse\\ gas emission}         \\ 
    \midrule
1.  & Ring and Douglas (2001)               & Finland   
        & International Journal of Retail \& Distribution Management
            & Viewpoint: reaching the consumer through e-grocery VMI 
                & Empirical & Ancillary & Core  & Absent    \\
2.  & K‰m‰r‰inen, SmÂros et al. (2001)      & Finland          
        & International Journal of Retail \& Distribution Management
            & Cost-effectiveness in the e-grocery business
                & Conceptual Analitycal    
                    & Absent    & Core  & Absent            \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Table is not complete, just has three first line to show, how to eddit your table and to show result.

If the `scriptsize` fonts are to small, than you should consider to use ˙˙sidewaytable`` environment, in which the table is rotated for 90 degrees.